How to calculate nozzle diameters for liquid mixing?
I need to build static mixer for 2 liquids. The liquids should flow from 2 different containers into common container because of vacuum force applied as shown on the picture.

The liquids can be be mixed in different volume proportions.
The liquids can have different viscosity.
The liquids should completely drain into the common container at the same time moment.
So how to calculate nozzle diameters (or square) depending on needed volume ratio and viscosity of each liquid?
Do the lengths of the nozzles affect on process too? If yes, how to count this in the formula?

if you use orifices, then the ratios will be fixed for given viscosities temperature etc. If you use valves then the ratios will be adjusted.

Are the containers enclosed? If so, I don't think it is possible to fully drain them using vacuum behind the nozzle, because the end equilibrium state might look like some vacuum in the mixing chamber and some vacuum in the containers nad both liquids half way through their respective nozzles. Maybe you could avoid this using flexible (collapsible) containers or you may need to use pistons.

How different are the viscosities? Are you talking about oil and water or molasses? Even different grades of oil can have widely different viscosities. Are the containers open to atmospheric pressure?
